# Rails not displaying rows on which association value is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller stockdiaries

```
 Ticketline.joins(:ticket, :product => :location)
```

ticketline belongs to product and product belongs to location.

Ticketlines table has a column PRODUCT, products table has a column LOCATION.

A product can have value in LOCATION column nil.

If I list all ticketlines in a table in view, ticketlines containing a product with location nil are not shown. The entire row.

While I'd expect to show the row and perhaps if I call:

```
ticketline.product.location.try(:NAME)
```

just show empty value in that column.

If I remove from my controller :product => :location it shows all rows.

Values in database are:

```
TICKET, LINE, PRODUCT, ATTRIBUTESETINSTANCE_ID, UNITS, PRICE, TAXID, ATTRIBUTES, PRODUCT_COST, PRICESELL, TAXES, SERVICES, SERVICES_RATE, HISTORY_ID
    'd0d82dbb-f6eb-41b3-a03e-37846e0e011a', 0, '130', '', 1, 850000, '001', '', 350000, 850000, 85000, 0, 0, 0
    'ec586062-af32-423e-82f7-0de1da9cffdd', 0, '121', '', 1, 1600000, '001', '', 650000, 1600000, 160000, 0, 0, 0
```

In this case there are 2 lines, one contains a product for which location is nil. That row is not shown.

How can I keep the join :product => :location (as I need to get data from location table for each product) while displying all records, also those with a product that has nil as value on LOCATION column?

Comment: Normally it includes all values my friend. can you please give me a sample of your data. What actually comes as output and what is the expected output?

Comment: Hi I updated the answer with values in database. Now it shows only one row while it should show 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`joins()` function by default work as `INNER JOIN` that's why it is giving `nil` values, you need to do `LEFT JOIN` instead.

```
 Ticketline.joins("LEFT JOIN tickets ON ticketlines.ticket_id = tickets.id LEFT JOIN products ON tickelines.product_id = products.id LEFT JOIN locations ON products.location_id = locations.id")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer I didn't know about the  default INNER JOIN, that will be useful for the future.. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
Ticketline.joins(:ticket).joins("LEFT JOIN products ON tickelines.product_id = products.id").joins("LEFT JOIN locations ON products.location_id = locations.id")
```

The above query will INNER JOIN the ticket and LEFT JOIN products and locations. This will produce the needed results.